# Does "这很大钱! 再见大学钱...." make sense? Or have I written it wrong?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters

For my Chinese class, I have to make a film recording an exchange in a restaurant. I'm trying to say "This is a lot of money! Goodbye college money..." in reference to someone spending too much on their meal.

Comment: note CL 笔 for sums of money, e.g.in 那笔巨款

Answer (score 1):

That does not really make sense. "A lot of" here means a great amount, while 大 means big as in size. Also 大学钱 does not make sense either. Instead you would say "大学学费" (college tuition)

So a better translation would be “这好贵啊！再见我的大学学费” (this is so expensive! goodbye my tuition)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "这很大钱! 再见大学钱...." is not grammatically correct in Chinese.

A more accurate translation of "This is a lot of money! Goodbye college money..." in Chinese would be:

"这太贵了！大学的钱再见了... "

This sentence uses the correct vocabulary and grammar to convey the meaning of your original sentence.